# Fix compile error when template instantiated with non-scalar type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
   #include <limits>
   #include <iostream>
   using std::cerr;

   template< typename T >
   int get_max_if_integral()
      {
      if ( std::is_integral<T>::value ) return (int) std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
      else return 0;
      }

struct S {};

int main()
   {
   cerr<<"int: "<<get_max_if_integral<int>()<<"\n";
   cerr<<"short: "<<get_max_if_integral<short>()<<"\n";
   cerr<<"float: "<<get_max_if_integral<float>()<<"\n";
// cerr<<"S: "<<get_max_if_integral<S>()<<"\n";
   }
```

This returns the desired result...

```
int: 2147483647
short: 32767
float: 0
```

However, if I uncomment the final line, I get:

```
x.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int get_max_if_integral() [with T = S]’:
x.cpp:22:40:   required from here
x.cpp:11:82: error: invalid cast from type ‘S’ to type ‘int’
       if ( std::is_integral<T>::value ) return (int) std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

I would for the function to return `0` in this case.

Comment: [constexpr if](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qEJmMJgkvpkzF3Zm) would do the job, but that's c++17.

Comment: @BlackMoses: Awesome!

Comment: To clarify, since the answer doesn't explain: The error is caused because with regular `if`, [both branches are visible to the compiler](http://ideone.com/zQTmqu); since `(int) std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is invalid when `T` is `S`, the compiler complains even though it'll never be executed.  With SFINAE, each branch is a distinct function.  With constexpr if, the `false` branch is discarded before compilation, effectively making it work like inline SFINAE.

Comment: In both cases, [only one branch is visible to the compiler at a given time](https://godbolt.org/g/RnynLh), meaning that it'll never see `(int) std::numeric_limits<S>::max()`.  (Note how `One<true>()` is identical to `Two<true>()`, and `One<false>()` is identical to `Two<false>()`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose you to split your function in two distinct functions, SFINAE enabled

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type
     get_max_if_integral ()
 { return (int) std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type
     get_max_if_integral ()
 { return 0; }
```